# How to scale captured image (with camera) to the size of specific PictureBox?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, picturebox

I want to scale captured image and show it in the picture box which I have located in the form.

When I do it like this (where `filename` is the name of the captured image and `imgImage` is the pictureBox)

```
imgImage.Image = new Bitmap(filename)
```

then only part of the photo can be seen on the screen ( according to the resolution ).

EDIT:

The problem here is that (I think) there is a version of Bitmap's constructor

`Bitmap(string filename, int width, int height)` or even `Bitmap(Image, Size)` but it's not supported on mobile framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking about windows-mobile I assume you are on the Compact Framework.

Here is an article on how to resize images on the compact framework: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Robs-Image-Shrinker